# Ejecutar comando o script en Raspberry Pi apenas se encienda

Tags: cmd, raspberry-pi

BUenas queria preguntar como podria hacer para que un script o un comando se ejecute en un raspberry pi 3 apenas se encienda. Necesito que este corra comandos de formato.js y .cmd

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta, para que tenga aceptación y una respuesta de calidad, así como para que sea útil para otras personas en el futuro. Primero, completa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y mira también: [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Tal como estrá la pregunta ahora mismo, tanto la pregunta como alguien que la responda recibirá seguro votos negativos, y mientras peor puntución de la pregunta, menos probable que se responda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias crear un archivo bash que ejecute este programa python y copiarlo en la carpeta init.d, todos estos script se ejecutan al arrancar el sistema, te paso una pagina web del foro de la propia rasperry pi donde te lo explican, es necesario que sigas el de este foro y no otro ya que cada distribución se comporta de manera diferente.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=70520

Te pongo un ejemplo del script que tienes que hacer, que es lo mas lioso de todo

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          </home/pi/hotspot>
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage my cool stuff
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
# If you need to source some other scripts, do it here

case "$1" in
 start)
  log_begin_msg "Starting my Hotspot service"
  python <PATH_DE_MI_PROGRAMA>
  log_end_msg $?
 exit 0
 ;;
stop)
log_begin_msg "Stopping the Hotspot service unfortunately"

# do something to kill the service or cleanup or nothing

log_end_msg $?
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/home/pi/hotspot {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
  esac
```